# Unique maximum degree in tournament

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, random-graphs

Consider a uniform random tournament with $n$ vertices. (Between any two vertices $x,y$, with probability $0.5$ draw an edge from $x$ to $y$; otherwise draw an edge from $y$ to $x$.) Let $p(n)$ denote the probability that there is only one vertex with the maximum out-degree. What is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p(n)$?

I would be surprised if this statement hasn't been written and proved anywhere, but I can't find it. Does anyone know of a reference, or a result that implies it?

Comment: The number of tournaments with a unique winner is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A013976 – the total number of tournaments on $n$ vertices is $2^{n(n-1)/2}$, so you can do some calculations to see whether it looks like the probability is going to one.

Comment: I get $p(16)$ to be about $0.64$. Why are you sure $p(n)\to1$?

Comment: Not only the maximum outdegree but quite a few of the largest outdegrees are unique.  This is known and I'm looking for a place it is written down.  It can be proved by fairly elementary means.

Comment: Hmmm, not in the places I looked.  The proof is almost the same as proving that the maximum degree vertex of a random undirected graph is unique, in Bollobas' book "Random Graphs".  Convergence is slow: for tournaments it passes 90% at around 900 vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find a published proof of this known result, but here is a close miss.

In [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/reader/82426260), page 256, is a short proof that a random undirected graph has a unique vertex of maximum degree almost surely.  If you replace "graph" by "tournament" and "degree" by "out-degree", the exact same proof works for tournaments.

The reason this works is that the degree of a given vertex in a random graph, or out-degree in a random tournament, have the same binomial distribution Bin$(n-1,\frac12)$.  Moreover, the degrees/out-degrees of different vertices are almost independent.